# Pagination in TypeORM/NestJS

Tags: javascript, orm, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I have to introduce pagination in `findAll()` method. I really dont know how to do it. I tried but it is giving so many errors. I used `findAndCount()` method given by `typeorm` for that, But I am not sure how it will work.

As of now below method returning all the record. I need to return at a time 10 records. Please suggest what modification I need to do.

```
async findAll(queryCertificateDto: QueryCertificateDto,page=1):  Promise<PaginatedResult> {
    
    let { country, sponser } = queryCertificateDto;

    const query = this.certificateRepository.createQueryBuilder('certificate');

    if (sponser) {
        sponser = sponser.toUpperCase();
        query.andWhere('Upper(certificate.sponser)=:sponser', { sponser });
    }

    if (country) {
        country = country.toUpperCase();
        query.andWhere('Upper(certificate.country)=:country', { country });
    }      
    const  certificates = query.getMany();     
    return certificates;
}
```

this is `PaginatedResult` file.

```
 export class PaginatedResult {
        data: any[];
        meta: {
          total: number;
          page: number;
          last_page: number;
        };
      }
```

I tried changing code of `findAll()` but `where` clause is giving error. I am not sure how to handle `query.getMany()` in `pagination`.

```
 const take = query.take || 10
        const skip = query.skip || 0
       
      
        const [result, total] = await this.certificateRepository.findAndCount(
            {
                where: query.getMany(),   //this is giving error
                take:take,
                skip:skip
            }
        );
        return result;
```

I need to introduce pagination in this method. Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: ``where`` clause is generally for providing a conditon. In your case ``query.getMany()`` does not not provides a condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `.getMany()` with your `where` in the last code, the result is an array of the data you need.

From your first code, you can do this:

````
async findAll(queryCertificateDto: QueryCertificateDto,page=1): Promise<PaginatedResult> {
    // let's say limit and offset are passed here too
    let { country, sponser, limit, offset } = queryCertificateDto;

    const query = this.certificateRepository.createQueryBuilder('certificate');

    if (sponser) {
        sponser = sponser.toUpperCase();
        query.andWhere('certificate.sponser = :sponser', { sponser });
    }

    if (country) {
        country = country.toUpperCase();
        query.andWhere('certificate.country = :country', { country });
    }

    // limit and take mean the same thing, while skip and offset mean the same thing
    const certificates = await query
        .orderBy("certificate.id", "ASC")
        .limit(limit || 10)
        .offset(offset || 0)
        .getMany();

    // if you want to count just replace the `.getMany()` with `.getManyandCount()`;

    return certificates;
}```
````

Comment: thanks. it is returning every time only first 10 records.

Comment: you're are welcome, if you want more records, just pass the limit as a query with the number of records you need and it will override the default limit which is 10,

10 is the default value,  so if you don't pass any specific limit it will return 10
records.

so for example, if you want 40 records, and you want it to start from  an id of 11 
the offset will be 10 and the limit will be 40.

In a nutshell, having a limit is just saying I don't want more than this number of values,
while offset is saying skip this number of records and start from here.

Comment: and because databases id's start from 1. An Offset of 0 while will start from 1 because you are saying skip 0 rows, likewise, 10 will start from 11, saying skip 10 rows

Comment: actually I am not using id which starts from 1. I am using id as uuid. which is alphanumeric number

Comment: Yes, it will still work.

Answer (score 6):

Typeorm has a really nice method specific to your usecase `findAndCount`

```js
async findAll(queryCertificateDto: QueryCertificateDto):  Promise<PaginatedResult> {

    const take = queryCertificateDto.take || 10
    const skip = queryCertificateDto.skip || 0
    const country = queryCertificateDto.keyword || ''
    const sponser = queryCertificateDto.sponser || ''
    

    const query = this.certificateRepository.createQueryBuilder('certificate');

    const [result, total] = await this.certificateRepository.findAndCount(
        {
            where: { country: Like('%' + country + '%') AND sponser: Like('%' + sponser + '%') }, order: { name: "DESC" },
            take: take,
            skip: skip
        }
    );
     
    return {
        data: result,
        count: total
    };
}
```

More documentation about Repository class can be found [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)

Comment: I am struggling there only Tushar. Can you guide me how can I use the same method in my code? I have put the code which I tried to use but dint work. I have edited my question.

Comment: why do you need the query var? I don't see that you are using it afterwards